# lose focus when onChange event of controller in react hook form change

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a form that contains an accordion. I have a form that contains an accordion. when we click on submit btn .If the text fields are empty, show errors and helper text. In this case, when we write the first letter to fill the text fields, the text field is out of focus.When you click on the text field again, you can fill the text field without going out of focus.

In other words, if the value of the text field is changed after showing the error, the component will be rendered And it exits the error mode. If you click again and fill the text field. You will no longer see the effect of going out of focus.

I would be grateful if you could help me solve this problem.:)

/my custom component/

```
const TextFildControler: React.FC<ITextFildControler> = ({
  requiredRule = "required",
  required = true,
  helperText,
  control,
  setFormDataChanged,
  IsReturnPathName = false,
  inputError,
  inputName,
  label,
  key,
}) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={inputName}
      control={control}
      defaultValue={""}
      rules={{ required: requiredRule }}
      render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
        <TextFildCustom
          {...field}
          value={field.value}
          key={key}
          required={required}
          fullWidth
          disabled={IsReturnPathName}
          label={label}
          error={inputError}
          helperText={helperText}
          inputProps={{ maxLength: 40 }}
                    
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default TextFildControler;

/mycomponent /

\<TextFildControler
inputName={`reports.${reportIndex}.reportsReturnPayment[${paymentIndex}].returnPaymentsbank`}
control={control}
requiredRule=""
required={false}
setFormDataChanged={setFormDataChanged}
label="bank"
inputError={!!errors.reports?.\[reportIndex\]?.reportsReturnPayment?.\[paymentIndex\]?.returnPaymentsbank}
helperText={
errors.reports?.\[reportIndex\]?.reportsReturnPayment?.\[paymentIndex\]?.returnPaymentsbank
? (errors.reports?.\[reportIndex\]?.reportsReturnPayment?.\[paymentIndex\]?.returnPaymentsbank as FieldError).message
: " "
}
/\>
```